# Excel: How to return found value in sequential order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to populate a little matrix in Excel with the values from a list that contains the project priority and the Squad that is supposed to do the project.

The returned value should be the `"priority"` number found in the list.

I have tried index match and it returns the values correctly but I would like to know how to do it without keeping empty spaces.

I am attaching a picture to further explain the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you try a Nasted `IF()`, at least show us what did you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$H$2:$H$25/($I$2:$J$25=A$1),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: This is the better answer as AGGREGRATE is a less intensive calc than my proposed array formula.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

I used this *array* formula in cell E2 and copied over and down (NOTE- array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just Enter):

```
=IF(ROW(E1)>COUNTIF($B:$C,E$1),"",SMALL(IF($B$2:$C$21=E$1,$A$2:$A$21),ROW(E1)))
```

Comment: You can wrap the small(if()) in IFERROR and save some typing: `=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($B$2:$C$21=E$1,$A$2:$A$21),ROW(E1)),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner That's true, but IFERROR is 2007+ only, so it wouldn't work on earlier versions of Excel, plus it will perform the entire calculation (which is admittedly rather intensive) before it gets to the error.  With the COUNTIF check, it will prevent unnecessary intensive calcs from the array portion of the formula.  As a rule of thumb, I try to limit the number of intensive calcs this way instead of using IFERROR.

Comment: Fair point, I rarely use Excel for this type of thing any more.  If I can't do it in SQL quickly, I will only do a one off and dump the results into the report needed at that time.  So I am all about less typing.